# why do I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I keep an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0" even though i've referenced this array bounds in the method.

```
`public class USCrimeLibrary  

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    USCrimeObject crimeObject = new USCrimeObject(args[0]); `
```

and the reference object:

```
`public class USCrimeObject {
private Crime[] crimes;
String fileName = "/Users/jpl/Developer/Java/CMIS141/WK8/Crime.csv"; 
public USCrimeObject(String fileName) {
this.crimes = new Crime[20];
readFile(fileName);
}`
```

Comment: You have to pass the arguments in order to use one.

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: I use MS visual Studio Code. output to terminal. I tried to output to debugger but error: Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class USCrimeLibrary
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: USCrimeLibrary (class file version 55.65535) was compiled with preview features that are unsupported. This version of the Java Runtime only recognizes preview features for class file version 56.65535

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to pass an argument while running the program.

But from your code I think a slight change in your code can make it executable without passing argument while running the program.

Change constructor `USCrimeObject` to

```
public USCrimeObject() {
this.crimes = new Crime[20];
readFile(fileName);
}
```

and from main class create `USCrimeObject` without argument

```
USCrimeObject crimeObject = new USCrimeObject();
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I couldn't figure out how to do that on MS Visual Studio Code for some reason